# Extent parameters in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, typegraphql

I've got graphQL code like below. My question is, if there is any option to write values of parameters as extent ? Or I must write all the values next to each other ?
For example, I want this [1-15], not this [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
Thanks !

```
const queryGraphQL = {
    query: `query {
  products(searchInput: {
    parameters: [{
      id: 915
      values:[4095,4096,4170]
    }
    ]

  },
          settingsInput: {limit:35 }) {
    products {
      producer{
        link
        name
        id
      }
      awardedParameters {
        id
        name
        values {
          name
          link
        }
      }

    }
  }
}`,
}
```

I tried to put it in [] but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think that would work.

Comment: You must create a custom scalar of type `String` and decode from string `"[1-15]"` to an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]`. However, I think it's better to list all the values in the array so you can leverage GraphQL types, completition and checks

Comment: Yes, probably the list would be better, but what if we have got dynamic number of values ? For example, today You've got [2,4,5,6] in an array, but tomorrow You can have [5,6,7] (someone could delete and add new ones). What then ?

Comment: You have to describe what these values are